# Directory.CreateDirectory not exists in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I am trying to use `Directory.CreateDirectory` in .NET Core. But it seems like it doesn't exist.
Is there any other way to create directory in .NET Core?
Here is part of my project.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Facebook": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Google": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Twitter": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
        "System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives" : "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0-beta-22816",
        "Mandrill.Client": "1.0.0-*",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Session": "1.0.0-beta4"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
        "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
        "ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },

    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "postrestore": [ "npm install", "bower install" ],
        "prepare": [ "gulp copy" ]
    }
}
```

I have dll-s successfully restored in .NET Core like on picture attached:
[image: NET Core reference]

---

Update: 
Issue does not exists. When I run this code on .NET Core it works. Only mouse over description is incorrect which says Not Available for .NET Core.
I recommend deleting this question.

Comment: Where did you declare this dependency? Can you paste your project.json?

Comment: @khellang I have included most of my project.json.

Comment: Issue is false positive. I will delete this question. When I run the code it works but in screenshot looks like it does not exists.

Answer (score 5):

### Fix Dependencies/Framework Assemblies

Since `System.IO.FileSystem` is a .NET Core dependency (full .NET framework already has these types in `System.IO` and `mscorlib`), you need to move it from `dependencies` to `dnxcore50.dependencies`.

Example:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx451": {
    "frameworkAssemblies": {
      "System.Collections": "",
      "System.IO": "",
      "System.Runtime": "",
      "System.Xml": "",
      "System.Xml.Linq": "",
      "System.Threading.Tasks": "",
      "System.Text.Encoding": ""
    }
  },
  "dnxcore50": {
    "dependencies": {
      "System.IO": "4.0.10-beta-*",
      "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.0-beta-*",
      "System.Reflection": "4.0.10-beta-*",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-*",
      "System.Threading.Tasks": "4.0.10-beta-*",
      "System.ComponentModel": "4.0.0-beta-*"
    }
  }
}
```

First, the `dependencies` node is for "framework agnostic" dependencies, i.e. dependencies that works on all frameworks you've specified under the `frameworks` node.

The `dnx451.frameworkAssemblies` (full .NET Framework 4.5.1) node is for GAC'ed assemblies, shipped with the full .NET framework. These are not downloaded through NuGet, but rather just referenced in your project.

Lastly, the `dnxcore50.dependencies` node is for .NET Core-specific dependencies. These are the new set of NuGet packages that together form .NET Core. These are downloaded and referenced using NuGet.

### Restore Packages

You need to make sure the package itself has been restored. Sometimes declaring the dependency in project.json isn't enough.

If you edit the project.json file in Visual Studio, it should automatically restore packages when saving the file. Otherwise you could try running [`dnu restore`](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility#restore-dnu-restore) in the project.json directory.

Also, you could try changing the version to `4.0.0-beta-*`.

Comment: Package is automatically restored. That is not a issue. I am seeing Directory class when I open System.IO.FileSystem using JustDecompile but when I mouse over Directory.CreateDirectory it say not supported in .NET Core...

Comment: I am not sure what will I get with that? If I have "System.IO.FileSystem": "4.0.0-beta-22816" in dependencies that dll is restored for both dnx 451 and dnxcore. I think that sections dependencies you suggest need to be used only if we have different dll-s for dnx451 and dnxcore and this is not that case right?

Comment: That is absolutely the case. You want to use the GAC'ed dll's for the full .NET framework (dnx451), and the new dlls from NuGet for .NET Core (dnxcore50). See my updated answer.

Comment: See the picture attached. I have successfully restored dll. That is not a issue here. I already looked into dll using JustDecompile. It even has required class and method...

Comment: So if everything is OK, what's the problem then? I understand that you've successfully restored the dlls. I only answered that because you didn't give enough information to go by at first. I give up...

Comment: As khellang has said, the System packages belong under `dependencies` for `dnxcore50`, not the overall project.